# Avoid duplicate strings while reading from a text file

Tags: python, api, twitter, duplicates

I've created a twitter bot to post descriptive adjectives from a list of 3000. I'm having issues where it'll crash with a Tweepy error saying status is a duplicate.

I feel the best solution would be to delete the line from the text file after printing. What would be the best way to implement this?

Here is the main part of the code I have written so far:

```
import random
import tweepy
import time
from auth import consumer_secret, consumer_key, access_token_secret, access_token

api = tweepy.API(auth)

starttime = time.time()
while True:
    file = open('words.txt', 'r')
    random_word = random.choice(file.readlines())
    tweet = ('The %s tree.' % random_word.strip())
    api.update_status(status=tweet)
    print('Tweeted: %s' % tweet)
    time.sleep(1800.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 1800.0))
```

After making some changes on suggestion of sshashank124, this is the updated code:

```
from random import shuffle
import tweepy
import time
from auth import consumer_secret, consumer_key, access_token_secret, access_token

 api = tweepy.API(auth)

    starttime = time.time()
    with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

    shuffle(lines)

    for line in lines:
        tweet = ('The {} tree.'.format(line))
        api.update_status(status=tweet)
        print('Tweeted: ', tweet)
        time.sleep(1800.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 1800.0))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have made sure there are no duplicates within the file the program is reading from.

Comment: You have a `while True`, what happens when you run out of unique choices?

Comment: Then all statuses have been posted and the bot can be retired

Comment: you should POP the line that you readed random choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem persisted even after editing the code so I found a solution in removing the randomisation from the program and randomising the text file instead. This way the program can read the lines in order and the words will still be displayed in a random order while avoiding duplication and error messages from twitter.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently reading the entire while during every iteration of the loop. The better option would be to read once, shuffle the lines and process them:

```
from random import shuffle

with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

shuffle(lines)

for line in lines:
    tweet = 'The {} tree.'.format(line)
    api.update_status(status=tweet)
    print('Tweeted: ', tweet)
```

Comment: Hi there, this didn’t work and the error message appeared again after some time. I thought from your code it looks like the file can only be opened once and therefore not have the same line read twice but it seems statuses can still be duplicates

Comment: @anhtz have you made sure there aren't any duplicates in the file itself? Also, can you edit your question (add, don't replace) and add the new code that you're using?

Comment: Each word in the text file is unique. Question has been edited, thank you

Comment: Then this is no longer related to the logic of the file-reading. This must be an error somewhere with the API/Twitter. Move the print statement to before the `api_update_status(...)` line to see which status causes it to error

Comment: After swapping the two lines, the status posted to Twitter without issue. I will leave it running for a while and hopefully the error doesn't re-appear. Thanks for all your help so far